# ruby multidimension array sorting

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this

```
arr = [[24,4], [44,5],[67,1], [30, 2], [67, 2]]
```

If i am using `arr.sort{|a,b| b[0]<=>a[0]}` i get this result

```
[[67,1], [67, 2], [44,5], [30, 2], [24,4]] -  #[value, id]
```

How to sort again the array to achieve this result

```
[[67,2], [67, 1], [44,5], [30, 2], [24,4]] -  #[value, id]
```

If there are same values, then the sort should happen on id descending .

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use `Enumerable#sort_by`:

```
arr = [[24,4], [44,5],[67,1], [30, 2], [67, 2]]
arr.sort_by { |x, y| [-x, -y] }
#=> [[67, 2], [67, 1], [44, 5], [30, 2], [24, 4]]
```

Comment: thanks tokland, is there any method to get results only for value > 50 from arr ?

Comment: use `select`. You should check the docs of Array and Enumerable.

Answer (score 4):

Why not take the simple and clear route:

```
arr.sort.reverse
# => [[67, 2], [67, 1], [44, 5], [30, 2], [24, 4]]
```